# Reference Native DLL in T4 Templates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, t4

I'm building a T4 template and I'm referencing my custom assembly, the custom assembly references a native DLL.

When I use the following syntax in my tt file :
<#@ Assembly Name="c:\projects\lib\xxx.dll" #>

I get the following error:
"Error  1   Failed to resolve assembly reference. The path 'c:\projects\lib\xxx.dll' must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone. If you have downloaded this template, you may need to 'Unblock' it using the properties page for the template file in Windows Explorer..

Even though, the file Does exist for sure.

I'm only guessing that the template also needs to load the com dll and not just the wrapper.

Comment: native dlls are imported via pinvoke.  assembly is to load managed assemblies